# Odoo - How to search by date

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to search a list of object based on date field

```
reservations = self.env['rm.reservation'].search([
    ('check_in', '=', self.check_in)
])
```

But when I run the Odoo, I get a runtime error

```
ValueError: Invalid field rm.reservation.check_in in leaf ('check_in', '=', datetime.date(2021, 12, 20))
```

This is the `check_in` field declaration in the reservation model class

```
check_in = fields.Date(string='Check In', required=True,
                       default=lambda self: fields.date.today())
```

Comment: Are you there is a check_in in `check_in` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is my fault, I should call

```
reservations = self.env['rm.reservation.room.line'].search([
    ('check_in', '=', self.check_in)
])
```

And this is solve the problem